# Why is the @ symbol being deleted in comments?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

When I try to start a comment with @ and then someone's name, the whole string -- the symbol plus the name -- is being deleted. Is that a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: meta.stackexchange.com might get you an answer faster (since that is a question about how the Q&A site engine works)

Comment: Testing: If you look at this comment, @Tommy, you’ll see that your name is not automatically removed.

Comment: @TriG, it only happens if the @ plus name is at the start. If you are not seeing your own name preceded by the @ sign in this comment, then you're seeing the problem.

Comment: Darn -- it worked that time! Sigh. I'll ask on meta.SE as MatthewMartin suggested.

Comment: @Tommy. Of course it worked that time, because *I didn't write the post to which these comments are attached.* You did. Which is why your name will probably be stripped from the beginning of this comment. This is all explained in my answer below.

Comment: @TriG notice my name was *not* stripped, and nor was yours from the one below (despite the fact that in that case you *were* the post author)

Comment: Yeah. At this point I'm confused too. I *know* there's an existing discussion of this on Meta SE, but I can't find it.

Comment: I just had a look, and there are umpteen related discussions. No way I'm venturing in there -- I'd get my newbie head ripped off :-) I think I'll just follow your approach and work the name into the middle of the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you comment, the owner of the post (question or answer) on which you are commenting is automatically notified. Therefore, mentioning their name is redundant. It doesn’t do any harm, but it isn’t necessary either.

Someone thought it would be a good idea to automatically remove such redundant names. I don’t know who thought this or why: it’s one of many incomprehensible decisions taken by the SO overlords, and is certainly more confusing than helpful. However, that’s the way it is.

I think they’re removed only when they occur at the very beginning of a comment. If you work them into a sentence, as I often do, they remain in place.

They also remain in place when the person has made comments themselves.

Comment: One problem that sometimes arises is that the comment text doesn't change if the user changes their username. So removing the hard link in favor of the existing soft link is actually more permanent.

Comment: @TriG Hmm, so now I'm in debug mode. As you can see in my above test to you, I failed to reproduce the problem. I wonder if it's because I immediately followed your name with a comma. In this comment, I've left out that comma. So, lets see if this comment begins with your @ name.

Comment: Ah bollox. Forget it. I'll take it to meta.SE if I see it again.